# Является ли устойчивой сортировка, встроенная в Windows в cmd и в Powershell?

Tags: сортировка, cmd, powershell

Является ли устойчивой сортировка, встроенная в Windows в команде sort командной строки и в командлете Sort-Object в Powershell ?

Напомню, что устойчивая сортировка – та, при которой два объекта **с одинаковым значением ключа сортировки** сохраняют свой относительный порядок. То есть если объект A был раньше объекта B до сортировки, то и после неё A останется раньше B.

Comment: Про powershell написано в документации https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.4#example-9-using-stable-sorts

Comment: Спасибо, насчёт Sort-Object понял: с ключом -STable – устойчивая